# grep doesn't terminate after showing requested number of matches

Tags: android, bash, grep, adb

I'm trying to use grep to output the first match and terminate. In my case the stream being searched comes from Android logcat, but this is probably irrelevant:

`adb logcat | grep -m1 SomeFilter`

I'm limiting the results to a single match using the -m option. If the input stream contains more than one match, the first match is shown and grep terminates as expected. However, if there is only a single match in the input stream, the match is displayed, but grep never terminates. Any idea why?

Comment: Maybe there isn't any `\n` in the input stream? Or EOF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have three ideas.

1) There is no LF symbol nor EOF in the input stream.

2) `grep` is actually terminating after seeing the first match. But the `adb` does not terminate despite `grep` exits and write to the pipe fails. `adb` just ignores these write errors and keeps running. You can check if `grep` has really terminated simply typing `pgrep grep` in another terminal.

3) Most likely, if there is really only a single match and nothing more, then probably `adb` does not write anymore to the pipe, and it never receives write error and SIGPIPE. Thus `adb` is still running whilst `grep` has actually terminated.

Comment: Actually, the more likely explanation is that `grep` exits after first match, but `adb` is only going to get a `SIGPIPE` on its next write to the pipe, so if `adb` writes a matching line and then hangs there for ten minutes before writing the next line, it won't get the `SIGPIPE` for the next ten minutes.

Comment: @4ae1e1 Yup. Thanks. Has edited my answer a moment before. =)

Comment: Adding the -d option ("Dumps the log to the screen and exits") to adb logcat solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's kind of an old question, but maybe this will help someone else who comes across this.  Another option if you can't use the -d option would be to do:

```
adb logcat -m1 -e "SomeFilter"
```